# d3 change class of clicked node text

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm trying to add a class to the label, that was clicked in my force diagram. For this I use a "click" function, which hands the clicked item to the update function (it updates the class of the item). I tried using *this* but then the console will report "*nodeClicked.childNodes[1].classed is not a function*".

Then I googled and tried to use "*d3.select(this).select("text");*" which does not report an error, nor update the text.

A node is a *< g > Element* which has two children: a circle and the text (the text I want to give a css class)

If you want to, you can look at my code snippet:

```
// Toggle children on click.
// Also save information about what was clicked and update the GUI
function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    }
    else{
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    // Save which node was just clicked now
    nodeClicked = d3.select(this).select("text");
    // Save the d3 data of this node
    nodeClickedData = d;
}
```

To change the class I tested both:

```
$(nodeClicked).addClass("nodeGreenMarked");
```

and:

```
nodeClicked.classed("nodeBlueMarked", true);
```

But none did anything. If I check in the console what content nodeClicked is, it tells me *"Array[1]" and when I open it: "0:< text >"*

Comment: Can you show a sample of the svg?

Comment: This is the one I used: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092
Is the console output "Array" correct?
If I just used "this" there was the correct svg text element there, but also the error "classed is not a function"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

D3 did somehow not correctly address the correct element (the text of the group element), no matter which of the possible methods I used (jQuery did somehow also fail). I must have keeping to oversee something really important, though I checked everything like 5 times.

No matter, I found a working solution: by adressing the DOM elements with pure javascript. The command I used to solve this and get the class applied correctly was

```
nodeClicked = this;
...
nodeClicked.classList.add("greenNode");
```

This adds the class greenNode to the group element. In my CSS file I wrote *.nodeClicked text* and put in the necessary CSS. So if you once also have problems addressing the correct element, you can also try to use this method.

Comment: I can not yet mark this one as "correct answer" - have to wait 2 days...

Comment: I don't know who downvotes a correct answer, but well... for me the pure Javascript solution worked.

Answer (score 10):

You can add class in two ways.

```
d3.select(this).select("text").attr("class",className);
```

OR

```
d3.select(this).select("text").classed(className,true);
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
d3.selectAll(".node").on("click", function() {
  //check if node is already selected
  var text = d3.select(this).select("text");
  if (text.classed("selectedText")) {
    text.classed("selectedText", false);
    //Remove class selectedNode
  } else {
    text.classed("selectedText", true);    
    //Adds class selectedNode
  }
});
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
.selectedText {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="500">
  <g transform="translate(120,20)">
    <path class="link" d="M0,262.85714285714283C90,262.85714285714283 90,197.1428571428571 180,197.1428571428571"></path>
    <path class="link" d="M0,262.85714285714283C90,262.85714285714283 90,328.57142857142856 180,328.57142857142856"></path>
    <path class="link" d="M180,197.1428571428571C270,197.1428571428571 270,131.42857142857142 360,131.42857142857142"></path>
    <path class="link" d="M180,197.1428571428571C270,197.1428571428571 270,262.85714285714283 360,262.85714285714283"></path>
    <g class="node" transform="translate(180,328.5714416503906)">
      <circle r="10" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></circle>
      <text x="13" dy=".35em" text-anchor="start" style="fill-opacity: 1;">Level 2: B</text>
    </g>
    <g class="node" transform="translate(180,197.14285278320312)">
      <circle r="10" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></circle>
      <text x="-13" dy=".35em" text-anchor="end" style="fill-opacity: 1;">Level 2: A</text>
    </g>
    <g class="node" transform="translate(0,262.8571472167969)">
      <circle r="10" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></circle>
      <text x="-13" dy=".35em" text-anchor="end" style="fill-opacity: 1;">Top Level</text>
    </g>
    <g class="node" transform="translate(360,262.8571472167969)">
      <circle r="10" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></circle>
      <text x="13" dy=".35em" text-anchor="start" style="fill-opacity: 1;">Daughter of A</text>
    </g>
    <g class="node" transform="translate(360,131.42857360839844)">
      <circle r="10" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></circle>
      <text x="13" dy=".35em" text-anchor="start" style="fill-opacity: 1;">Son of A</text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I also tried the "attr" command, and even the "style" command which did not work out. I guess when running the code, it is still somehow not adressing the correct element. Even I checked in the debugger a thousand times. It really is strange. But I found a solution using pure Javascript which finally worked for me! Thank you for your help. :)